# Buying pre-downloaded games from playstation plus

Tags: psn

What do I do if during my PS+ membership, I download a game, and after playing it, I want to buy it. However when I go to buy, it says "Already Purchased"?

Comment: Might have to wait for PS+ to lapse before it offers to let you buy it maybe? I've never had my sub lapse to check. And you're talking free on PS+ games right, not free trials? For free trials you have to run them once and let the 1 hour timer run down before PSN will let you purchase the game, it's a little awkward.

Answer (score 1):

You need a second "non PS+" account to buy either already "purchased" zero-price PS+ game, or just to buy a game at full price then it's on a PS+ zero-price "sale". And of course you can buy a game after your PS+ subscription ends.

This is an old known issue and it seems that Sony didn't really want to do anything about it.